# Codeigniter ion auth register insert user id into multiple tables

Tags: codeigniter

first sorry if its a stupid question but im lost a bit.

So when i use ion auth register function, and the register is ok, inserts the user data in the users table, and inserts the users id in to the groups table too.

Im a bit lost at this part, i would like to insert the user id in to the user profile table, and user settings table, after the registration is complete.

And i dont really know which function to modify. I was looking at the model and library searching for how the group is added into the database but couldnt really find any hint in the code.

So could someone please help me out on this? Pointing to a tutorial maybe or just giving me a hint where to start the modify

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `models/ion_auth_model.php` at line `733` starts the register function.

You can extend somewhere on line `793`, after the line that gets the id of the user `$id = $this->db->insert_id();` just add your custom data you wish to insert:

```
$mdata = array(
    'user_id' => $id,
    // ... your other data here
);
$this->db->insert('my_table', $mdata);
```

Comment: i feel a bit stupid now that line didnt caught my attention, thanks for your help and for spearing time in my question

Comment: No problem, I remember myself trying to find something there and failing at first. The file is structured strangely if structured at all.

Comment: one last question, this extedns the user id right? id = $this->db->insert_id(); because i added a query, inserts everything but the user id is always 0

Comment: What do you mean by extends? It takes the original user `id` of the user that was inserted most recently and you can use it as you wish.

Comment: ran into a strange problem, if i pass the $id in to the query what i made, it inserts id 0 both for groups and settings

Comment: Are you sure you are doing it after line `$id = $this->db->insert_id();` (line 792) ?

Comment: so sorry my bad, added under it and it works, so sorry, and sorry form bugging you